# Moving between panes in tmux on Windows

Tags: windows, bash

I'm using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows an trying out `tmux`. My [config from Ubuntu](https://github.com/liquidmetal/dotfiles/blob/master/.tmux.conf#L15-L18) works mostly perfectly except for the Alt+ shortcut.

My guess is the terminal window is the problem - it's not passing on the "Alt" button presses onto Bash. Is there a way to resolve this or would I have to change my bindings to use some other button (like Ctrl, etc)?